# Why won't my action's shortcut be executed?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, moose-technology

In Moose 4.6, here's my code:

```
finder := GLMFinder new.
finder show: [:a | 
    a dynamic display: (GLMTextPresentation new forSmalltalk);
    act: [self halt]
    on: $k 
      entitled: 'Implementors (k)' ].

finder openOn: 'Waaaaaaa'
```

If I click the little menu item, a debugger comes up. But, if I press apple-k, it doesn't. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that actions do not work well in the dynamic presentation. But it works flawlessly if you add the action to the inner presentation (in this case to the GLMTextPresentation).

```
finder := GLMFinder new.
finder show: [:a | 
    a dynamic display: 
        (GLMTextPresentation new forSmalltalk;
        act: [self halt]
        on: $k 
        entitled: 'Implementors (k)')
    ].

finder openOn: 'Waaaaaaa'
```